# Simulate new rows, Python is much slower than SAS, How to speed up?

Tags: python, pandas, sas

Here is the problem and it is for a model implementation task. Given I have some data. I need to simulate some new data,some of the variable values are dependent on the values of previous row and a random number r.

For example, say I have

```
AsOfDate  Var1  Var2    r
6/4/2018    A   0.3     0.2
```

Creating two rows, the output would be

```
AsOfDate    Var1    Var2    r
6/4/2018    A       0.3    0.2
6/5/2018    B       0.06   0.95
6/6/2018    A       0.057
```

The logic is, as of 6/4 r=0.2 less than Var2, then as of 6/5 Var1=B, Var2=0.3*0.2=0.06. As of 6/5, r=0.95 greater than Var2, then as of 6/6 Var1=A, Var=0.06*0.95=0.057.

I apologize if I confuse you. But I'm trying my best to describe this. I can't think of a way that I can do this without using a for loop. I ran the following simple SAS and Python code just to compare the speed. To my supprise, python/Pandas is much lower than SAS datastep. I'm no expert in Python, so I'm wondering if there is better way to do this and make it runs much faster. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
a=pd.DataFrame(data={'id':[1],'val':[2]})
tick=time.time()
n=0
b=pd.DataFrame()
for n in range(10000):
    a['id']=a['id']+1
    a['val']=a['val']+(n+1)
    b=pd.concat([b,a])
tock=time.time()
print(tock-tick)
```

time took: 7.54027533531189 sec

```
data test;
input id val;
datalines;
1 2
;
run;

%let _timer_start = %sysfunc(datetime());

data test(drop=i);
    set test;
    do i=1 to 10000;
        id=id+1;
        val=val+(i+1);
        output;
    end;
run;

data _null_;
  dur = datetime() - &_timer_start;
  put 30*'-' / ' TOTAL DURATION:' dur time13.2 / 30*'-';
run;
```

time took: 0.01 sec

Comment: The reason your python code is so slow is that you are re-writing the whole dataframe every time you add a row to it. This more than outweighs the potential I/O advantage of running in memory in python vs. on disk in SAS.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward answer is: because you have chosen the most inefficient way : )

I.e. this code (not really optimised):

```
import time
import pandas as pd
tick=time.time()
n=0
a = {
    'id': 1,
    'val': 2,
}
data = []
for n in range(10000):
    a['id'] = a['id']+1
    a['val'] = a['val']+(n+1)
    data.append([a['id'], a['val']])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'val'])
tock=time.time()
print(tock-tick)
```

Does  the same (unless i made some stupid mistake) few hundred times faster, probably not much slower than sas.

Comment: Thank you jbet. It is much faster! 0.01 sec vs 7.5 sec. It's as fast as SAS. I'd really appreciate help to optimize this code even more. I was hope Python would be a lot faster than SAS.

Comment: @DeadJoker They're all going to be about the same speed.  Different language, same computations.  Also, why would you need it to be faster than 0.01 seconds?  Don't prematurely optimize.

Comment: @Robert Penridge The actual model production code in SAS take about 3 hours to run and it needs to run everyday. That's why I'm exploring if I can write it in Python and make it much faster. It's unfortunate that I know very little JAVA and know nothing about C...

Comment: @DeadJoker You should consider optimizing the SAS program you have.  I'm guessing you're using some loopy macro that is unnecessary and inefficient.

Comment: @DeadJoker First identify the slowest sections of the program and then optimize those first.  There's no point trying to optimize something that takes 0.01 seconds when there's probably other parts taking minutes or tens of minutes.

Answer (score 0):

if you can, build your data outside pandas

```
from itertools import accumulate
a = list(range(2, 10002))
b = [2+i for i in accumulate(range(1,10001))]
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'id':a,'val':b})
```